"Either" not only with present simple but with other tenses as well
I see sentences like "Either she does it or she dies". Can we use other tenses with "either"? For instance "Either she will do it or she will die". If not please explain why?

Either she will do it or she'll die; either she didn't do it or she died. Both fine.

@MichaelHarvey still, present simple is really common with "either". Do you know why? Like I am sure my version with future simple is correct because you approved it but it is less common.

You may seen a form of words such as 'either something happens or something else happens'  in which the verbs in the first and second parts (separated by 'or' ) are in the present tense, e.g. 'either she leaves or I do'. These are a type of threat, promise, or prediction. If the first thing does not happen, the speaker is saying that the second thing is inevitable - either you get a job or I seek a divorce, either he takes his medicine or he dies, either you work harder or you get fired.

either has zero to do with tenses.

Yes, you can definitely use other tenses with "either." The phrase "either... or" is used to present two alternatives, and it doesn't restrict which tense you use. So, using different tenses depends on the context and what you're trying to express.
For example, in your sentence:
"Either she will do it or she will die" is perfectly correct. This uses the future tense to talk about two possible outcomes in the future.
Or an example in the past tense:
"Either my dog wandered off, or someone took him in."

And we can mix, too: Either you finished the project already or I will not hire you again. Either he will travel to my place for dinner, or I cooked for nothing (a bit ironic, but still colloquial)
